# assigning one structure/class object to another with operator "="

Tags: c++, struct, structure, assign

I have structure `aa` and I'm trying to run such code:

```
aa * b = new aa;
aa * c = new aa;
c=b;
delete (b);
c.useSomeFunction
```

Can I use the object pointed to by `c` after destruction of `b`?

The same question in case of:

```
aa * b = new aa;
aa * c ;
c=b;
delete (b);
c.useSomeFunction
```

Comment: Note that the title does not match the question. You are not assigning a structure to another, but rather assigning one pointer to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title of the question is misleading, because you don't use an `operator=()` in your code. You only assign pointers which are built-in types.

As pointed out before:

In your first example, the pointer assignment yields a memory leak, as the object `(*c)` can no longer be deleted. Also you cannot call a function of `(*b)` (even if pointed to by `c` after deleting object `(*b)`.

In your second example you don't get the memory leak. Note that in production code you should initialise every pointer with `nullptr`. Also here you cannot access a function of `(*b)` after deleting the object.

the call to the function must be `c->useSomeFunction()` in order to by syntactically correct.

What you probably want (and is suggested by the title) is to create a new object and assign the content of the old one to it. Something like:

```
struct aa {
  aa():x(0),y(0){}
  aa& operator=(const aa& rhs);
  int foo(){return x-y;}
  int x;
  int y;
};

aa& aa::operator=(const aa& rhs){
  if (this == &rhs) {return *this;}
  x = rhs.x; 
  y = rhs.y;
  return *this;
}

int main(){
  aa *b = new aa();
  aa *c = new aa();
  *c = *b;
  delete(b);
  c->foo();
  delete(c);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In your examples both pointers point to the same object, so after destroying it neither of them is valid. Also, in your first example `c=b` is an automatic memory leak since you lose the ability to free what you allocated in `aa * c = new aa`.

---

Also this can't be real code, since `b.usesomefunction` wouldn't compile. You meant `b->use..`.

Comment: @Hogan No, `c=b` is legal but it means the object can no longer be freed.

Comment: @Hogan I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: @Hogan: there's no such thing in C or C++.

Comment: My point was this -- a memory leak means you lose reference to allocated memory that you can't free.  But if you point at an object and then delete it, the memory has been freed but in this case he is  pointing to bad memory.  If he uses/access that bad memory he might have things work or at some point (when new info is there) he will get a panic or other crash as he are stepping on memory he does not control.  This is not a leak per-se because he has freed the memory.

Comment: @Hogan once OP does `c=b` in the first example, there is no handle to delete the object originally pointed to by `c`.

Comment: @juanchopanza - True, I was looking at the second example.